# MySQL event scheduler set expiration date on data and auto update if expired

Tags: php, mysql

How do I set my data on MYSQL to expiration on date? And how to auto remove `SILVER` package from `User1` on expired date and auto update to `FREE` package.

`User2` and `GOLD` package has the same question as `User1`.

For an example :

I would like to set expiration date for `SILVER` and `GOLD` package like this :

```
SILVER Package for 1 Month (30 days)
GOLD   Package for 2 Months (60 days)
```

`User1` buy a `SILVER` package on `27/1/2559 16:20` and this package has been remove from `User1` on `26/2/2016 16:20` then auto update to `FREE` package for `User1`.

`User2` buy a `GOLD` package on `15/3/2559 16:20` and this package has been remove from `User2` on `14/5/2016 16:20` then auto update to `FREE` package for `User2`.

**tbl_package**

```
| id | name   |
---------------
| 1  | FREE   |
| 2  | SILVER |
| 3  | GOLD   |
```

**tbl_member**

```
| id | name  | package |
------------------------
| 1  | User1 | SILVER  |
| 2  | User2 | GOLD    |
| 3  | User3 | Free    |
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add a timestamp column to `tbl_member`, such as the expiration date. Set the column so it is null by default. When the user upgrades, update this new column in your PHP code.

Something has to run in order to change the expired packages. While the most efficient option is an automatic cron script which runs on a daily or hourly basis, you could simply run it every time a user logs into the site. You want to modify the packages for each row of `tbl_member` that have an expiration date in the past. Changing the value package of the package column is essentially the same as "removing" it. Additionally, you want to set the expire date to null because the free package never expires.

For example, this SQL should downgrade any members to the Free package if the expire date is in the past:

```
UPDATE tbl_member SET package="Free",expire=null WHERE expire < now()
```

Comment: Hopefully this helps you; please let me know if anything doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's auto remove and change it to FREE package?

Comment: By changing to the free package, you're essentially removing the silver/gold package.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a **cron jobs** to do this, it will check every day to find expried member and update them. You can read here http://goo.gl/VJIHkE